# error: uncaughtException: require(...).invokeRolesPolicies is not a function

Tags: node.js, mean, meanjs

I am using MEAN.JS for developing a web app, but for some reason after I made few changes, well mostly copied and paste new modules into the app I see the error as below:

> error: uncaughtException: require(...).invokeRolesPolicies is not a function

I dont know why is this happening, anyone has any clue how to fix this?

This is the whole error message:

> TypeError: require(...).invokeRolesPolicies is not a function
>       at C:\oferdo\oferdo\config\lib\express.js:180:39
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Object.module.exports.initModulesServerPolicies (C:\oferdo\oferdo\config\lib\express.js:179:32)
>       at Object.module.exports.init (C:\oferdo\oferdo\config\lib\express.js:252:8)
>       at C:\oferdo\oferdo\config\lib\app.js:29:23
>       at C:\oferdo\oferdo\config\lib\mongoose.js:36:15
>       at C:\oferdo\oferdo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:284:19
>       at open (C:\oferdo\oferdo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:511:17)
>       at C:\oferdo\oferdo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:518:7
>       at C:\oferdo\oferdo\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:1504:5
>       at handleCallback (C:\oferdo\oferdo\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:96:12)
>       at _callback (C:\oferdo\oferdo\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:1420:5)
>       at C:\oferdo\oferdo\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:1463:7
>       at C:\oferdo\oferdo\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:1416:5
>       at finish (C:\oferdo\oferdo\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\auth\scram.js:157:16)
>       at handleEnd (C:\oferdo\oferdo\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\auth\scram.js:170:7)
>       at C:\oferdo\oferdo\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\auth\scram.js:264:17
>       at commandCallback (C:\oferdo\oferdo\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:1194:9)
>       at Callbacks.emit (C:\oferdo\oferdo\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:119:3)
>       at null.messageHandler (C:\oferdo\oferdo\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:358:23)
>       at Socket. (C:\oferdo\oferdo\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:292:22)
>       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
>       at TCP.onread (net.js:531:20)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is nothing to do with incorrectly named files.

You need to make sure that you have the `invokeRolesPolicies` function defined within your policies file. The minimum required is:

```
'use strict';

var acl = require('acl');
acl = new acl(new acl.memoryBackend());

exports.invokeRolesPolicies = function () {};
```

The reason why is that the express.js lib defined in mean.js assumes this is set, and tries to call it, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get this error if you have an incorrectly named file under your module's server > policies directory, so check there for any inconsistently named files.

**EDIT**

I see now that it's not the naming of the file but if you have a file in the policies directory that doesn't contain this method, it will produce this error. In my case I had temporarily commented out the code in a file in this directory in preparation for removal.